# Basic signal communication

Tags: bash

I have a bash script, its contents are:

```
function foo {
    echo "Foo!"
}

function clean {
    echo "exiting"
}

trap clean EXIT 
trap foo SIGTERM

echo "Starting process with PID: $$"

while :
do
    sleep 60
done
```

I execute this on a terminal with:

```
./my_script
```

And then do this on another terminal

```
kill -SIGTERM my_script_pid # obviously the PID is the one echoed from my_script
```

I would expect to see the message "Foo!" from the other terminal, but It's not working. SIGKILL works and the EXIT code is also executed.

Using Ctrl-C on the terminal my_script is running on triggers foo normally, but somehow I can't send the signal SIGTERM from another terminal to this one.

Replacing SIGTERM with any other signal doesn't change a thing (besides Ctrl-C not triggering anything, it was actually mapped to SIGUSR1 in the beginning).

It may be worth mentioning that just the signal being trapped is not working, and any other signal is having the default behaviour.

So, what am I missing? Any clues?

EDIT: I also just checked it wasn't a privilege issue (that would be weird as I'm able to send SIGKILL anyway), but it doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: +1: Well worked out question, showed what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash runs the trap only after `sleep` returns.

To understand why, think in C / Unix internals: While the signal is dispatched instantly to bash, the corresponding signal handler that bash has setup only does something like `received_sigterm = true`.

Only when `sleep` returns, and the `wait` system call which bash issued after starting the `sleep` process returns also, bash resumes its normal work and executes your trap (after noticing `received_sigterm`).

This is done this way for good reasons: Doing I/O (or generally calling into the kernel) directly from a signal handler generally results in undefined behaviour as far as I know - although I can't tell more about that.

Apart from this technical reason, there is another reason why bash doesn't run the trap instantly: This would actually undermine the fundamental semantics of the shell. Jobs (this includes pipelines) are executed strictly in a sequential manner unless you explicitly mess with background jobs.

Comment: The standard workaround is to run `sleep` in the background and immediately `wait` on it: `sleep 60 & wait`, since `bash` can interrupt the `wait` command to handle the pending signal. You would want to do something trickier like `sleep 60 & sleep_pid=$!; wait` so that you could also kill the `sleep` command from the appropriate handlers, if desired, in case `sleep` hasn't finished yet.

Comment: @chepner: Interesting. I didn't know that and I'm not sure why I would want that. In my case, `wait` exits with code `143` on `TERM` (but only when `TERM` is trapped, which makes it even messier). It seems all to be pretty well described in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#When_is_the_signal_handled.3F

Comment: In the end I wanted more control and ended up using C, but as you're pointi g out what was wrong I'll mark this as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The PID that you originally print is for the `bash` instance that executes your script, not for the `sleep` process that it is waiting on. During `sleep`, the signal is likely to be ignored.

If you want to see the effect that you are looking for, replace `sleep` with a shorter-lived process like `ps`.

```
function foo {
    echo "Foo!"
}

function clean {
    echo "exiting"
}

trap clean EXIT 
trap foo SIGTERM

echo "Starting process with PID: $$"

while :
do
    ps > /dev/null
done
```

Comment: Ok it works as I intended, but what does ps do? Isn't ps a program to list your running processes? Does it mean something different while in bash?

Comment: I think the main detail here is that `sleep` is a bad test because the signal is likely being ignored during sleep. And yes, `ps` is an external program. Using `read` in the loop works too.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I editted the answer. I always thought `ps` was a `built-in` but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: The signal is not ignored; the handler is simply blocked from running until the `sleep` command (which is not interruptible) finishes and control returns to `bash`. Or perhaps more accurately, the signal is not *delivered* until control returns to `bash`.

Comment: @chepner: My understanding is that the signal is delivered immediately (for some hand-wavy definition of immediately) as I described in my answer. The *handler* is run immediately, but the *trap* is only executed after bash resumes its work when `sleep` finished.

Comment: @JoSo That sounds right. I (incorrectly) use *trap* and *handler* synonymously.